# Permutation between two vectorizations of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Suppose a 2$\times$3 matrix $A$
$$\begin{bmatrix} A_{11} & A_{12} &A_{13}\\ A_{21} & A_{22} & A_{23}\end{bmatrix}$$ 
is vectorized as $Vec(A)=\begin{bmatrix} A_{11} & A_{12} & A_{13}&A_{21} & A_{22} &A_{23}\end{bmatrix}^T$.

We can also define $Vec(A^T)=\begin{bmatrix} A_{11} & A_{21} &A_{12} & A_{22} & A_{13} & A_{23} \end{bmatrix}^T$.
So What is the transformation(permutation) matrix between $Vec(A)$ and $Vec(A^T)$?

More Generally, How to dertermine the permutation matrix between two vectorizations for $A$ of arbitrary size(e.g. $m$ rows and $n$ columns).

Answer (score 1):

These matrices are called "commutation matrices", another name sometimes popping up is "perfect shuffle". More precisely, a commutation matrix $\mathbf K_{m,n} \in \mathbb{R}^{mn \times mn}$ is the unique permutation matrix that satisfies

$$\mathbf K_{m,n} \cdot {\rm vec}(\mathbf A) = \mathbf {A^{\rm T}}\quad \forall \mathbf {A} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}.$$

These matrices have some fun properties. For instance, they can be used to permute a Kronecker product, like this:

$$\mathbf K_{m,n} \cdot \left( \mathbf {A} \otimes \mathbf {B}\right) \cdot \mathbf K_{p,q} =  \mathbf {B} \otimes \mathbf {A}$$

for all $\mathbf A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times p}, \mathbf B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times q}$.

There are a couple of nice references by Magnus and Neudecker that discuss these matrices and their properties. I highly recommend [MN79] and [MN95, ch. 3] (you can find both on google).

Btw: If you should need extensions of this to multi-way arrays (linked to permutations of multi-way Kronecker products), I studied those in my dissertation so I could help with this as well.

[MN79] J. R. Magnus and H. Neudecker, “The commutation matrix: some properties and applications,” The Annals of Statistics, vol. 7, pp. 381–394, 1979.

[MN95] J. R. Magnus and H. Neudecker, “Matrix differential calculus with applications in statistics and econometrics,” John Wiley and Sons, 1995.
John Wiley and Sons, 1995.